# Spring boot admin mixed content and not show styles in server https

Tags: spring, spring-boot, admin

I deployed my app spring boot admin in server https but no show styles , when deployed in server http its ok, but in hhtps no show.

Is there a way to show the page in the server https?
[capture of spring boot admin in server https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ1pd.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a default login page over https and it contains insecure content received over http, you will see a message like "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure content 'http://...'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS..."
I fixed that by setting the Content-Security-Policy header to "upgrade-insecure-requests" value. It instructs browser to treat all of a site's insecure URLs (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure URLs (those served over HTTPS).
You can do it like this in the security configuration of your Spring Boot Admin server application:

```
http.
    ...
    .and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy("upgrade-insecure-requests");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding this to my application.properties

```
spring.boot.admin.ui.public-url=https://your-sbadmin-url/admin
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).